# emacs Aborted (core dumped)- centOS 7.0 emacs 25.3 -- Please Help

Tags: debugging

Dear stackexchange users,

I would really appreciate your help in fixing my issue.
I am new with centOS 7.0 with less a year of experience.
I was using emacs-24.3 until the following error came up, so I compiled emacs-25.3 with source code. I tried to purge gtk without a success. This issue persists for weeks, and I really don't know what to do.

I would fully appreciate your help..

When I type `emacs any.log` the following Error shows up:

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X protocol error: BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation) on protocol request 130
When compiled with GTK, Emacs cannot recover from X disconnects.
This is a GTK bug: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85715
For details, see etc/PROBLEMS.
Fatal error 6: Aborted
Backtrace:
emacs[0x500792]
emacs[0x4e8659]
emacs[0x500823]
emacs[0x4b9dc1]
emacs[0x4bd945]
emacs[0x4bd9ce]
/usr/lib64/libX11.so.6(_XError+0x12b)[0x7fc8a5a6a07b]
/usr/lib64/libX11.so.6(+0x420d7)[0x7fc8a5a670d7]
/usr/lib64/libX11.so.6(+0x42195)[0x7fc8a5a67195]
/usr/lib64/libX11.so.6(_XReply+0x208)[0x7fc8a5a68088]
/usr/lib64/libX11.so.6(XQueryPointer+0x8e)[0x7fc8a5a5e0be]
/usr/lib64/libgdk-3.so.0(+0x4f80c)[0x7fc8a78a380c]
/usr/lib64/libgdk-3.so.0(+0x6ed9d)[0x7fc8a78c2d9d]
/usr/lib64/libgdk-3.so.0(gdk_window_get_device_position_double+0x12d)[0x7fc8a7895b0d]
/usr/lib64/libgdk-3.so.0(gdk_window_get_device_position+0x2d)[0x7fc8a7895bfd]
/usr/lib64/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x342c41)[0x7fc8a7e4ec41]
/usr/lib64/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x34312f)[0x7fc8a7e4f12f]
/usr/lib64/libgdk-3.so.0(+0x22338)[0x7fc8a7876338]
/usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x4aeed)[0x7fc8a61d1eed]
/usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_dispatch+0x159)[0x7fc8a61d14c9]
emacs[0x5c8c18]
emacs[0x5966b1]
emacs[0x4f2c8d]
emacs[0x4f492f]
emacs[0x4f6446]
emacs[0x557d0d]
emacs[0x4e8b8c]
emacs[0x557cbb]
emacs[0x4e8b47]
emacs[0x4ecf74]
emacs[0x4ed295]
emacs[0x417318]
/usr/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7fc8a1eaac05]
emacs[0x417e1c]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks to be a [known GTK+ bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85715).  It appears from [https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1355274](this discussion) that running emacs with `XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1` in your environment will fix it.

You can try it by running `XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1 emacs any.log`.

You could also try rebuilding emacs and calling `configure` with `--with-x-toolkit` set to something like `athena` or `no`.  I tried it with both `athena` & `no`, and either option resulted in a perfectly decent-looking emacs.  The menu & tool bars (and I assume scrollbars too — I didn't check those) are subtly different, but still quite usable.  Many folks disable them anyway!

Comment: You are so awesome. Thank you very very much! It is fixed. I will remember and pass on if any people have the same issue. Awesome!