# Emacs 26.1 RC1 display issues over SSH/X11 with xming/vcxsrv

Tags: ssh, x11, gtk3, emacs26

I can compile Emacs 26.1 RC1 ok, and use it locally on the host fine.

However, when attempting to ssh -X to host via PuTTY 0.70 and launch the Emacs gui, emacs is not displaying correctly. See screenshot below - no default welcome screen, and missing minibuffer too.   Using Windows xserver program VcXsrv (1.19.6.3).

[image: Emacs 26.1 RC1 GTK3 display issue]

I suspect this issue is related to some combination of GTK and Xming/VcXsrv, however the behavior does change between Emacs 25.3 and 26.1 RC1, see table below:

```
| emacs    | x-toolkit | result
+----------+-----------+-------
| 26.1 RC1 | gtk3      | bad
| 26.1 RC1 | gtk2      | bad
| 26.1 RC1 | motif     | ok
| 25.3     | gtk3      | ok
| 25.3     | gtk2      | ok
```

- `emacs -Q` produces the same result.
- freshly compiled on Opensuse Leap 43.2 and CentOS 7 produces same result
- `XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1 emacs` same result

  - References: [Link1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1355274), [Link2](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/40990/emacs-aborted-core-dumped-centos-7-0-emacs-25-3-please-help)

./configure options I ultimately desire:

`--with-x-toolkit=gtk3 --with-xwidgets  --with-modules --with-mailutils`

Where gtk3 is required for xwidgets, so motif or other x-toolkits are not the best solution.

Note: with Xming 6.9.0.31  (not vcxsrv)
I get core dumps with error messages referencing this GTK bug:
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85715

Can anyone else replicate this problem or have any ideas how to resolve?

```
wget ftp://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/pretest/emacs-26.1-rc1.tar.xz
tar -xvf emacs-26.1-rc1.tar.xz
cd emacs-26.1
./configure --with-x-toolkit=gtk3 --with-xwidgets --with-modules --with-mailutils --prefix=/home/test/emacs_26.1_gtk3
make && make install 
# launch emacs, confirm ok
# login to windows, launch ssh -X putty session to linux host, + vcxsrv/xming
# launch emacs - compare to screenshot
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please, please, pretty please `M-x report-emacs-bug` rather than send such things here!  Please!  Release candidates (and beta-releases as well) aren't there for users to play with it and discuss problems among themselves, but so that such issues are reported to the maintainers so they can hopefully fix them before the release.

Comment: Submitted. Will post link when accepted

Comment: I also reproduced on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed w/GTK+ Version 3.22.29

Comment: https://lists.gnu.org/r/bug-gnu-emacs/2018-04/msg00658.html

Answer (score 6):

Emacs 26 by default switches on double buffering for X servers when it finds the `Xdbe` header on the build machine. (See [Emacs 26 release notes at the GitHub mirror](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/etc/NEWS.26).) Some X servers don’t support this.

Therfore switching off double buffering by adding `'(inhibit-double-buffering . t)` to your frame parameters might fix this. Safest way is to add it to `default-frame-alist`:

```
(setq default-frame-alist
         (append default-frame-alist '((inhibit-double-buffering . t))))
```

Credit: This tip comes originally from the [bug-gnu-emacs](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/bug-gnu-emacs) list. (Thanks Eli and Robert!)

Comment: I believe there is an extra trailing ")" that needs removed, otherwise that works. Also the original suggested solution is here: https://lists.gnu.org/r/bug-gnu-emacs/2018-04/msg00821.html

Comment: @bscipio Thanks! You're right. I have updated the answer.