# Emacs 26 build on RHEL6 has blank window frame

Tags: x11, build, emacs26

I just built Emacs 26.1 (stable) on Centos 6 (RHEL 6.9). When I fire up the executable with `src/emacs -Q` over X11 it shows an empty window with no minibuffer:

[image: Failing Emacs 26.1]

I built Emacs without gnutls, but that should be possible. Do I miss any essential libraries?

According to [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/41021/emacs-26-1-rc1-display-issues-over-ssh-x11-with-xming-vcxsrv) the issue might be related to the X-toolkit I'm using (GTK2). Does Emacs 26 not support GTK2?

The output of my `./configure --without-gnutls` can be seen in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/halloleo/46808e9574f375f1e320f5e13c068296); the output of the `make all` in [this](https://gist.github.com/halloleo/c4a4ac53c047d972b6f7b91a0240167f).

### Notes:

1. The build runs fine in a terminal via `src/emacs -Q -nw`
2. I have built Emacs 25 on the same machine and it runs successfully over X11.

Comment: Not an expert on this, but I'd try starting Emacs in GDB and looking for suspicious messages it might print during initialization.

Comment: Text inside the frame isn't drawn with any widget toolkit, and GTK2 widgets seem to show correctly. It's either a problem with double buffering introduced in 26 or freetype2.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 It *is* caused by double buffering. See [the answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/42439/9387).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs 26 by default switches on double buffering for X servers when it finds the `Xdbe` header on the build machine. (See [Emacs 26 release notes at the GitHub mirror](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/etc/NEWS.26).) Some X servers like *MobaXTerm* don’t support this.

So just switch off double buffering by adding `'(inhibit-double-buffering . t)` to your frame parameters. Safest way is to add it to `default-frame-alist`:

```el
(setq default-frame-alist
      (append default-frame-alist '((inhibit-double-buffering . t))))
```

Credit: This tip comes originally from the [bug-gnu-emacs](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/bug-gnu-emacs) list. (Thanks Eli and Robert!)